# Display corruption with fglrx drivers

Tags: drivers, ati, display, screen-corruption

I've been having some problems with the AMD 12.10 and 13.1 drivers. Basically there always appear to be flashing lines going across my screen. It happen all the time and every key input makes it flicker. It is severely annoying and I really need to find a way to fix it without going back to the open source driver.

How do I resolve this issue? I've attached a screenshot below, if you look at the top where the folders are you can see random black and white lines.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try turn off display compositing in window manager tweaks*, there seems to bee a issue there
or only turn off display fullscreen overlay windows directly*

atleast try to turn off everything related to 3d desktop and see if that fixes the issue

- this is on xubuntu 12.10 (XFCE) but might be the same for you too, hope my answer helps